# Find the 3rd div with class after particular div

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a class of `active`. I need to find the 3rd div after this div with the class `.slide-item`.

I have tried:

```
$('.active').next('.slide-item').next('.slide-item').next('.slide-item img').data('src');
```

But it can't be the right way to do this... can it?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eq` to select an element by index. Try this:

```
$('.active').nextAll('.slide-item').eq(2).find('img').data('src');
```

There may still be a better method of achieving this, but without seeing your HTML it's hard to advise you.